# Rails 5.1.2 problema con AJAX

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Quiero implementar ajax para crear un post, sin tener que recargar la pagina y que no se vaya a la vista show como regularmente lo rails, lo estoy haciendo siguiendo un tutorial pero no funciona.

en el _form.html.haml pueden ver que agregue el remote: true para trabajar con ajax.

```
= form_for @post,remote: true do |f| 
  - if @post.errors.any?
  #error_explanation
  %h2= "#{pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this post 
  from being saved:"
    %ul
      - @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
        %li= message

  .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.full-width
    = f.text_area :body, class:"mdl-textfield__input"
    = f.label :body, "Comparte con la Comunidad", class:"mdl-
    textfield__label"
  .actions.text-right
    = f.submit 'Publicar', class:"mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--
    raised mdl-button--colored"
```

sin embargo cuando el post es creadom, la aplicacion me redirige a la pagina show del post recien creado en formato html, pero deberia haberse quedado en el formulario.

yo no se si es un problema con la version de rails 5.1.2, por que en rails 4 bastaba con tipear remote: true para que la aplicacion se quedara en el formulario despues de darle al boton para crear un post.

post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
   end
end

# PATCH/PUT /posts/1
# PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update(post_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /posts/1
# DELETE /posts/1.json
def destroy
  @post.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:body)
end
end
```

tambien tengo un archivo show.js.erb para hacer render de un parcial y ver el body del post recien creado.

show.js.erb

```
$('#posts').append("<%= render j @post %>")
```

_post.haml

```
%article
  =post.body
```

tengo rato buscando, en las guias de rails dicen que para trabajar con ajax solo necesito el remote: true pero no me esta funcionando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo dos problemas que pueden ocasionar el mal funcionamiento de tu código:

1) Estás esperando una respuesta `js` pero el controlador únicamente responde a `html` y `json`; intenta agregando el formato `js` en la acción; por ejemplo:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update(post_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      format.js { render :show }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js { }
    end
  end
end
```

2) El uso de `j` es equivocado, debes ponerlo **antes** del `render` (el resultado de `render(@post)` es el que debe *escapar del javascript*:

```
$('#posts').append("<%= render j @post %>")
```

Comment: si, de hecho intente eso antes de preguntar aca y de esa manera no se va al show, pero no hace render del parcial que quiero mostrar.

Comment: @JoseRafaelCamacaroBarraez He encontrado el problema; son dos puntos: 1) Asegúrate que tengas `render :show` dentro de `format.js {...}` y 2) El uso de `j` es incorrecto (va **antes** de `render`). Revisa nuevamente mi respuesta pues ya la he actualizado para reflejar estos comentarios.